# Angular routeParams returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, route-provider

I'm trying to use the angular routeProvider and routeParams to get the id and name parameters.
Here's the js:

```
angular.module("test",["ngRoute"])
 .config(["$routeProvider",function(a){
     a.when("/test/:id",{}).
       when("/tests/:name",{});
     }
 ]).controller("testCtrl",["$scope","$routeParams",function(a,b){
     a.result = b.name; //console.log(b.id);
 }
]);
```

And the HTML

```
<html ng-app="test">
...
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
<p>Test ID</p>
<a href="/test/1">1</a>
<a href="/test/2">2</a>


<p>Test Name</p>
<a href="/tests/test1">Test1</a>
<a href="/tests/test1">Test2</a>
<a href="/tests/test1">Test3</a>


<p>RouteParams Result</p>
<p>{{ result }}</p>
</body>
```

This is not a SPA and hence I'm not setting the templateUrl and controller in **when** function. I only need the URL params. I have included the angular and angular-route libs

[Here's the plunkr just in case](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bi8L4FyEu5U2DYZ6lYee)

Comment: Does adding the controller to your when objects fix the issue? ie. when("/test/:id",{ controller: 'testCtrl' })

Comment: Nope, returns undefined as before

Answer (score 1):

```
 a.when("/test/:id",{}).
   when("/tests/:name",{
     controller: "testCtrl"
   });
 }
```

You need to specify controller to the current state in order to get routeParams.

Comment: As i mentioned above, i'm explicitly leaving that out as my controller changes for each view(Say id=1, id=2)

Comment: Then you need to use $routeChangeStart function to get the params of current state

Comment: I have modified the links. The app isn't a SPA using normal routeProvider and routeParams. I only need access to the params in the url. I tried $scope.$on("routeChangeError"),routeChangeSuccess. But the event isn't fired.

Comment: $locationChangeStart is fired but even this prints empty object